# BWEB - Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I need a solve for this.
I tried this code but it dont really works...
Thanks for answers!!!
I need a solve for this.aaaaaaaasdsfgghhjmjjjajjajaosqujjqjqqjalolas
I tried this code but it dont really works...
Thanks for answers!!!

List kiolvasaslista = new List();

```
    private void kiolvasas()
    {
        kiolvasaslista.Clear();
        string sor = "";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Melleklet_4EIT_B20.txt"));

        while ((sor = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] tomb = sor.Split('|').ToArray();
            arfolyam a = new arfolyam();
            a.Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(tomb[0].Trim());
            a.Valuta = tomb[1].Trim();
            a.Arak = Convert.ToDouble(tomb[2].Trim());

            kiolvasaslista.Add(a);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public double KiolvasniAzArfolyamotANapon(DateTime Datum, string valuta)
    {
        kiolvasas();
        foreach (arfolyam aa in kiolvasaslista)
        {
            if (Datum == aa.Datum && valuta == aa.Valuta)
            {
                return aa.Arak;
                
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool BeirniAzArfolyamotANapon(DateTime Datum, string valuta, double Arfolyam)
    {
        kiolvasas();
        using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Melleklet_4EIT_B20.txt"))) 
        {
            
            foreach (arfolyam a in kiolvasaslista)
            {
                SW.WriteLine(a.Datum + "|" + a.Valuta + "|" + a.Arak);   
            }

            SW.WriteLine(Datum + "|" + valuta + "|" + Arfolyam);
            
            
        }
        return true;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> OsszValutaKiolvasasa()
    {
        kiolvasas();
        List<string> alista = new List<string>();
        foreach (arfolyam a in kiolvasaslista)
        {
            if (!alista.Contains(a.Valuta))
            {
                alista.Add(a.Valuta);
            }
        }
        return alista;
    }
```

I need a solve for this.
I tried this code but it dont really works...
Thanks for answers!!!